# Gegenbauer polynomial relation with complex argument

Tags: cv.complex-variables, polynomials, analytic-continuation

Gegenbauer polynomials, $C_j^{\nu}(t)$, are defined to be the coefficient of $h^j$ in the expansion $(1-2ht +h^2)^{-\nu}$. It can be shown using *[Higher Transcendental Functions, Vol 1, Harry Bateman, (1953), Section 3.15.1 (13)]* that for $\vert t \vert \leq 1$, the following inequality is true:
$$\Bigg\vert C_j^{\frac{n-2}{2}}(t)\Bigg\vert \leq Cj^{n-3}$$

where $n \geq 3$.

Given that inequality is true for real values of $t \in [-1, 1]$, I want to know if we can extend this inequality to a disk in the complex plane of radius 1, i.e. $\{z \in \mathbb{C} \;\big\vert \;\vert z \vert < 1\}$?

Given that we are considering polynomials, they are analytic. Also, $[-1, 1]$ is a subset of the disk in the complex plane of radius 1 that contains at least one accumulation point. Thus it seems plausible that the result above could be extended for complex argument, $z$, using analytic continuation.

Am I on the right track or is there something I am missing. I am new to analytic continuation so any help would be amazing!

Comment: the extension will be tricky since if $n=3$ we get the Legendre polynomials $P_n$ where the inequality above says that $|P_n(x)| \le C, x \in [-1,1]$ and that is true for $C=1$ actually; however if $|z|<1, z$ non real there is a unique root $|w|>1$ of the quadratic $w+1/w=2z$ and $P_n(z)$ is asymptotic to $a(z)w^n/\sqrt n$ where $a(z)$ is uniformly bounded (below and above) in $|z|<1$, when away from the real line (eg $|\Im z| \ge \delta>0$), so $P_n(z)$ has exponential growth in $n$

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you tell me why $P_n(z)$ is asymptotic to the function with the $a(z)$? I am not sure where you got this from? @Conrad

Comment: This is a standard result in the theory of orthogonal polynomials and can be found in the usual textbooks like Szego's Orthogonal Polynomials chapter 8 (has a nice formulation of the full asymptotic) or Whittaker and Watson classic A Course of Modern Analysis chapter 15; essentially follows from the basic integral representation  (the $w^n$ is obvious since it is the maximal value of the integrand and it decays asymptotically away from it,  but the coefficient and the square root of $n$ require some work)

Comment: @Conrad Hello again, I have been looking at Szego's Orthogonal Polynomials Chapter 8 as you suggested but I can't find the formulation discussed above. Do you know where it is exactly?

Comment: theorem 8.21.1 page 194 - it clearly states that $P_n(z)$ is asymptotic to $cn^{-1/2}a(z)w^n$ where $w=w(z)$ is the largest modulus root of the quadratic $w+1/w=2z$, or if you prefer $w=z+\sqrt {z^2-1}$ with the determination of the square root st $|w|>1$ when $z \notin [-1,1]$, while $a(z)=(z^2-1)^{-1/2}w(z)^{1/2}, c=(2\pi)^{-1/2}$

Comment: OK I see now! I didn't notice that $w +1/w = 2z$ can be written as $w = z + (z^2-1)^{1/2}$ and then this matches the formula you kindly pointed out. I am thinking that my result above might not work because if it grows exponentially then I will presumably have to keep shrinking the disk that I am working on in order to keep the inequality? Do you have any ideas of how to show that?

Comment: Could you give a few more details as to how you obtained the inequality? It is obviously bounded by the value at $x=1$, which is simply $(n-2)_j/j!$, where $(a)_k$ is the rising factorial, but that is not the same as your polynomial bound in $j$. Do you know the value of $C$ exactly?

Comment: @Sellerie So I originally got the bound from a paper called "Partial Regularity of the Zero-Set of Solutions of Linear and Superlinear Elliptic Equations" by Cafferelli and Friedman. In that paper, they do what I state above, i.e. use the result in "Higher Transcendental Functions" to show the inequality above. I am not sure how they do this and it is something I have been trying to figure out. Interestingly, I have found another way prove it that involves the bound of the polynomial at $x=1$ to do this.

Comment: Does that mean it is a worse bound than just bounding the function by its maximum at $x=1$?

Comment: I am not sure I understand fully what you mean by "worse bound". The Gegenabuer polynomials on the interval [-1, 1] are bounded by the Gegenabuer polynomials evaluated at 1. However, you can bound the value of the Gegenabuer polynomial at 1 from above as in the inequality in the OP. This is not what is done above however. Above, the authors used a formulation for the Gegenabuer polynomials to obtain the result that has nothing to do with the value of the Gegenabuer polynomials at 1. I am unsure of how they did it, but given its in a published paper, I took it to be true.